# TypeError: 'binaryType' getter called on an object that does not implement interface WebSocket

Tags: node.js, socket.io

В мозилле и в IE выдает ошибку

```
TypeError: 'binaryType' getter called on an object that does not implement interface WebSocket.
```

На строке

```
if (this.ws.binaryType === undefined) {
    this.supportsBinary = false;
}
```

в socket.io на стороне клиента.

В Google Chrome и Opera все ок.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто обновил библиотеку на стороне клиента
http://socket.io/download/